# How to get an value from a php page with js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to capture a value that is calculated on a PHP page called "classes_day.php" at the same time as I pass a value per GET, "? Day = YYYY-mm-dd" to it. How do I do this with JS or JQuery?

```html
<?php
  
  // aulas_dia.php

 include '../config.php';

 $exped_duration = 14*60;

 if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
  $data = $_GET['data'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE `dia` LIKE ".$data."";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
  $soma = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $soma = $soma+$row['duration'];
  }

  $aulas_free = floor(($exped_duration-$soma)/50);
  echo $aulas_free;
 }

?>
```

I already tried using an iframe and contentwindow, but iframe gets the value and the contentwindow is empty (weird isn't it?).

---

Following Barmar's tip, I'm using $ .get, but I don't know why this loop is not working, can anyone help me?

```html
for (i = 0; i < num_days; i++) {
  x = (first_day+i)%7;
  y = (first_day+i-x)/7;
  h_dia(String(y)+String(x),i+1);
  data_c = ano+"-"+mes+"-"+String(i+1);
  $.get("aulas_dia.php?data="+data_c, function(data){ 
    console.log(String(y)+String(x)+" - "+data_c+" - "+data); 
    set_aulas_fun(String(y)+String(x),data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Use an AJAX request.

Comment: In jQuery you can use `$.get()`.

Comment: Note you need to use the same name for the GET parameter and array index. You have `Day=` as your get parameter name but are using `$_GET['data']`. You need to change one of them to match the other

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.get()` to send an AJAX request.

```
$.get("classes_day.php?data=YYYY-MM-DD", function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

BTW, you can add up all the durations in the SQL query instead of using a PHP loop. And you should use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php
include '../config.php';
$exped_duration = 14*60;

if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    $query = "SELECT SUM(duration) AS total FROM `task` WHERE `dia` LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $data);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $soma = $row['total'];
    $aulas_free = floor(($exped_duration-$soma)/50);
    echo $aulas_free;
}
```